# issue in share from wordpress in web.config

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

im try share from my wordpress  website on plesk under iis 10

all  posts on my website  when share on facebook   redirect to home page
any Any Help please
web.config code

```
    <rewrite>
     <rules>
      <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect"  url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
<rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
     
     </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. What is your question? Please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: when share on Facebook from my website any post  redirect to home page  and  not share

Comment: <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" /> is this your homepage? What is your purpose in creating this rewrite rule?